# how to display an image in flutter after every 5 seconds?

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, flutter-animation

i am new at flutter and building a project in which a distractor appears after every 5 sec on the the screen. i am using timer periodic but it the picture does not appears after 5 seconds rather it get displayed randomly after a few times. it starts to flash the image on the screen rather then keeping it displayed. also pictures doesnt appear after set time rather it changes its time itself. please help me. i am sad.

...

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class adhd1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const adhd1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<adhd1> createState() => _adhd1State();
}

class _adhd1State extends State<adhd1> {
  int a = 4;
  bool distractor1 = false;
  bool? distractor2 = false;
  bool? distractor3 = false;
  bool? distractor4 = false;

  late Duration tt;
  late Duration ff;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    showD1() {
      Timer.periodic(
          tt = Duration(seconds: 4),
          (Timer t) => setState(() {
                distractor1 = true;
                t.cancel();
              }));
      Timer.periodic(
          ff = Duration(seconds: 5),
          (Timer d) => setState(() {
                distractor1 = false;
                d.cancel();
              }));
      if (distractor1) {
        return SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/character_robot_attack0.png",
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ));
      } else {
        return const SizedBox(
          height: 200,
        );
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
          children: [showD1()],
        )));
  }
}
```

...

Comment: sorry if someone wants to help me they can use anypicture they want just please i have a deadline and helppppppppppp meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 0):

To show for 2 second and hide 5sec, I am using `AnimationController`

```dart
class AnimeTestW extends StatefulWidget {
  AnimeTestW({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnimeTestW> createState() => _AnimeTestWState();
}

class _AnimeTestWState extends State<AnimeTestW>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      reverseDuration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    )
      ..addListener(() {
        print(controller.status);
        if (controller.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          controller.reverse();
        }
        if (controller.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          controller.forward();
        }
        setState(() {});
      })
      ..forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        controller.reverse();
      }),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("A"),
          if (controller.status == AnimationStatus.forward)
            Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Use initState with a state bool

```dart
class _adhd1State extends State<adhd1> {
  Timer? timer;

  bool showImage = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        showImage = !showImage;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            if (showImage)
              Image.asset(
                "assets/images/character_robot_attack0.png",
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thankyou for your help. What this does is it displays the image for 5 sec and removes it for 5 seconds. What i want is for the picture to display for 2 sec and vanish for 5 seconds. This is where the periodic timer starts to work wrong. it changes its duration itself randomly. Please can anyone help me. what i want is specific timer for it that displays the image for 2 seconds and vanishes for 5 seconds repeatedly with same interval. Thankyouu

Comment: Try 1st widget  `AnimationController`

Comment: thanyou so much for your help man. it means alot

Comment: can u help me with another thing. In distractor file each image has a boolean that is showimage. I want to to know the real time value of that showimage in another dart file that is my layout file where i call the distractors. i want to know when user presses a button whther the showimage was true or not. how can i do that?